# 403 permission to server access

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am programming, and suddenly I can't assec my website.

The error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2 Server at project.vanmarijn.nl Port 80
```

Am i blocked on my server???
And i can't right now on the Direct Admin to look if i'm blocked or unblock myselff, so how can i unblock myself in that case???

It happend when i was using and changing the .htaccess file

Comment: FTP to your site and then show us the .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete or rename the .htaccess from SSH or from an FTP client.

It basically says that the content of your .htaccess is bad.